# How can I detect if a var was passed and then block it from passing again?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, if-statement, fetch

I have a quick question, My project is a quick 4 option answers, With radio buttons and pictures displayed, Now I have the pictures and the answers stored in a text file, That way my JS detects what it reads and then passes it to HTML, Now I use this function to pick a random line:

```
fetch('./Test.txt', {
  credentials: 'same-origin',
  mode: 'same-origin',
}) // reads the file  as a buffer
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.text();

  })
  .then(function(data) {

    a = data
    a = a.toString() // makes the buffer into a readable string
    a = a.split('\n') // makes all the items in the list
    randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * {The number of lines that you have in the text file}) // makes a math equation to get a random line from the text file
```

Now How would I detect if `randomNum` passed a line that was already passed? Or let's say, How can I check if function `randomNum` passed a  line that got passed?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Forgot to mention that ` a[randomNum] ` Gives you a random line.

Comment: @UsithaIndeewara , What I'm asking is that, When I get let's say line number 1, And it got displayed/Functioned, How can I store a cookie to tell the JS that this user have gotten line number 1, And tell the JS to NOT Display line number 1 for this user again?

Comment: Sorry if you don't understand my question, My question is that, How can I store a cookie that checks if this user got let's say line number 7, And to NOT display it again for the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your client-side Javascript code can maintain an array of pictures already seen and store that in a cookie. Execute the following statements inside your `function(data) {...}` in the place where you currently have `randomNum = Math.floor(...)`:

```js
var picturesSeen = JSON.parse((document.cookie || "a=[]").substring(2));
if (picturesSeen.length === a.length)
  alert("Sorry, no more pictures");
else {
  while (true) {
    var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * a.length);
    if (picturesSeen.indexOf(randomNum) === -1) {
      picturesSeen.push(randomNum);
      break;
    }
  }
  document.cookie = "a=" + JSON.stringify(picturesSeen);
}
```

The cookie will survive a page reload.

You can "reset" the cookie with the command

```js
document.cookie = "a=[]";
```

Comment: Would having a reload page function affect this snippet code? Since it's client-side and I don't call the function above, I just execute it on page load then refresh the page to get a new line, Or should I make it on a function call so it can at least store the cookie?

Comment: If my question wasn't clear, Here's a template on Repl.it of the whole project, https://replit.com/@lolt04588/Template?v=1 ,

Comment: Alright Thank you soo much for your help, It's very nice to see a place where you can just get help anytime you're stuck into something, I wish there's a "tip" function, Thank you soo much again, Much appreciated.

Comment: But last question, Would it reset automatically? Or how would I rest it?

Comment: See my augmented answer.